# Is there any way to save the perforce client view to a file for sharing among team

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-stream

I want to save the client view in a file so that any member of my team can use the same file and sync similar files. Something like this:

```
cd new_client_folder
export P4CLIENT=new_client_folder
cat nfs/old_client_view.txt | p4 client -i
```

I am looking for a way where old_client_view.txt will act as a template and it can automatically replace the root and view fields specified in the old_client_view.txt file.

Comment: Have you looked at streams?  The idea behind streams is to centralize client view management -- not only does everyone working on a particular branch start with the same view, but it can be dynamically updated across all workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save it as a file at all, but can save the client view as a template. Then simply import the template:

```
p4 client -t <client_template> -o <client_name> | p4 client -i
```

Comment: You can also simply do `p4 client -t <client_template>`

Comment: This is very fragile and I want to maintain the revision of this template file. I want to keep this file at a common place and want people to take it from there

Comment: @Mohit lock the template client so other people can't edit it.  Use a spec depot to preserve its version history.

Comment: I'd recommending adding a spec depot. It will version all of your client specs, users, etc. Very handy.

Comment: I don't have permission to create a spec depot

Comment: Your admin would. And if they haven't, they should do so, and at least give you permission to view clients.